# Is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS still supported for five years if I change the desktop environment?

Tags: upgrade, xfce, mate, support

I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this:

Will Ubuntu 20.04 LTS still be supported for five years if I change the desktop environment to MATE or Xfce?

And if I change the desktop environment to MATE or Xfce, can I then still do dist-upgrade without problems, or will my MATE desktop be changed into GNOME?

Or do I have to do the dist-upgrade from the GNOME desktop, and then log out and switch to MATE after?

I have been doing a lot of research and if I want a stable system that I can update instead of doing a fresh install every time the version reach end of life (I hate having to do that), then Ubuntu seem to be the best bet (rolling release would be to risky, that something might go wrong after an update) and the flavors only having three years support. But the GNOME desktop will slow down my laptop, Lenovo Thinkpad X300 6478, 4 GB RAM, 160 GB SSD, Core 2 duo 1.2 GHz - so having a different lightweight desktop installed would solve this.

Regarding flavors, can I do dist-upgrade on those or do I have to do a fresh install? I'm particularly interested in Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu.

I always do backup before attempting anything, on an external HDD using [Redo Backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redo_Rescue) and Multiboot USB.

I found this: [Upgrade Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start).

Comment: Packages included on the Ubuntu Desktop ISO come with 5 years of support; as to packages from 'restricted', but packages from 'universe' being community supported which include *flavor* desktops such as XFCE & MATE only have 3 years of support, so adding extra desktops will mean your system is partially supported after 2023-April (3 years from initial 20.04 release).

Comment: Ubuntu does **not** use `dist-upgrade` to *release-upgrade* for a number of reasons (*to improve stability & lessen the risk of problems primarily, yes that is part of the process but only part*) so much of your applies to off-topic systems.  If you read the release notes of the release you'll upgrade into (eg. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) you'll find instructions on how to upgrade & keep your Ubuntu system secure.

Comment: Flavors *release-upgrade* the same as main Ubuntu; with very rare caveats, eg. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last with LXDE thus upgrade was supported via re-install, Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS was the last using XFCE thus... etc but all those details are made clear in the release notes.

Comment: IMHO, we should not take this seriously. For example for some reasons (like having Qt4 and Python2) I still use Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS on about 20 machines. And Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS (EOL) in LTSP environment with capacity of 100 machines. So defacto you will get 3 years of support, but I would recommend to do not care about this. Use the version which you like more. Also please note that the 22.04 LTS will be released sooner than 20.04 LTS get EOL, so you can jump to it before 2025.

Answer (score 8):

Packages included on the Ubuntu Desktop ISO come with 5 years of support; as to packages from 'restricted', but packages from 'universe' being community supported which include flavor desktops such as XFCE & MATE only have 3 years of support, so adding extra desktops will mean your system is partially supported after 2023-April (3 years from initial 20.04 release).

eg.

On a QA-test install of Lubuntu *focal* daily performed yesterday (ie. what will be released as the 20.04.3 ISO) I get

```
guiverc@dc7700-2004:~$ ubuntu-security-status
1773 packages installed, of which:
1252 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2025
 521 could receive security updates with ESM Apps until 4/2030

Enable Extended Security Maintenance (ESM Apps) to get 1 security
update (so far) and enable coverage of 521 packages.

This machine is not attached to an Ubuntu Advantage subscription.
See https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

This shows the packages that have 5 years of support, and those that can be extended via the use of ESM.

Ubuntu does not use `dist-upgrade` to *release-upgrade* for a number of reasons (*to improve stability & lessen the risk of problems primarily, yes that is part of the process but only part*) so much of your question applies to off-topic systems.

If you read the release notes of the release you'll upgrade into (eg. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) you'll find instructions on how to upgrade & keep your Ubuntu system secure.

Flavors *release-upgrade* the same as main Ubuntu; with very rare caveats, eg. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last with LXDE thus upgrade was supported via re-install, Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS was the last using XFCE thus... etc but all those details are made clear in the release notes.

Comment: I'm not sure `ubuntu-security-status` helps here..  I know `ubuntu-support-status` on prior releases was great & useful for this comparison, but I've doubts about the results, and no time to explore sorry.

Comment: I thank you both for the clarification and the information, I have updated my question with a link on how to do the upgrade, so new users can find the correct method :)

Answer (score 4):

Both Ubuntu (Gnome) and Ubuntu MATE are made up of *packages*, and indeed share many of the same packages.

- Ubuntu (Gnome) 20.04 packages are supported for 5 years.
- Ubuntu MATE-specific packages are supported for 3 years.

If you want to do a release-upgrade (not dist-upgrade -- they are different), apt will attempt to upgrade ALL the packages that you have installed. If you still have Ubuntu (Gnome) packages installed, whether you use the Gnome Desktop or not, those packages will be upgraded.

- Dist-upgrades are *available*, but not *supported*. Release-upgrades (`do-release-upgrade`) are supported in Ubuntu. If you break your system by mis-using `dist-upgrade`, we will merely suggest that you re-install.

A "better" choice is a matter of opinion and personal preferences. We don't know you, so we don't know what is "better" for you.

There's a lot of hearsay and speculation in your question that I'm not going to bother to address beyond this advice: Since you are using a "*customized version of Ubuntu*," keep notes on how to duplicate your customization on a new install. ALWAYS be prepared to clean-install. Have backups, notes, and install media before beginning a release-upgrade. In 16 years, I've had a botched release-upgrade exactly once...and that was my own fault. However, perhaps I do things differently than you do.